# Comprimir if con array

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código que deseo "comprimir" o simplificar
¿se podría hacer con un array?

```html
<?php if ($row['tecnico'] == $_SESSION['username'] or 
   $_SESSION['username'] == "nameA" or 
   $_SESSION['username'] == "nameB" or 
   $_SESSION['username'] == "nameC" or 
   $_SESSION['username'] == "nameD") : ?>
```

Comment: Claro que se puede! lo intentaste???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias crear un array con las opciones que necesitas y usar `in_array` asi:

```
<?php $opciones = array('nameA', 'nameB', 'nameC', 'nameD');

if ($row['tecnico'] == $_SESSION['username'] or in_array($_SESSION['username'], $opciones)) : ?>
```

Comment: Te faltó un paréntesis de cierre

Comment: Tienes razon, ya edite.  Te funciono?

Comment: A la perfección! Gracias